# Increasing Eddy current induced within surface by attaching a magnet on surface

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

Magnets are commonly used in magnetic exercise bikes as brakes for increasing resistance:

[image]

[image]

where the black wheel is a piece of cast iron. I was wondering if (significantly) more eddy currents would be induced if the cast iron was slightly magnetised, e.g., attaching a piece of magnet on the black wheel. Does the polarity matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eddy currents inducted into a metal are determined by its conductivity, which, generally, would not be increased due to its magnetization.

So, magnetizing the disc or attaching a magnet to it would not improve the brake action.